# Aurelia Unable to find module with ID when setRoot with variable

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to follow this example of how to use aurelia in a multiple page application.

http://patrickwalters.net/creating-multipage-apps-using-aurelia-2/

When i do

```
  aurelia.start().then(a => {
    let start = 'app'
    a.setRoot(start);
  });
```

i receive the following error:

> Unable to find module with ID: app

- I already made this work with require. Maybe a thing with webpack?
- In the example 'start' receive a string from body element, i just want to make it easy to follow

Answer (score 0):

Webpack requires you to use `PLATFORM.moduleName` to declare your modulenames, see the docs: https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/wiki/Managing-dependencies

So you would need to write

```
import { PLATFORM } from "aurelia-pal";
...

aurelia.start().then(a => {
    let start = PLATFORM.moduleName('app');
    a.setRoot(start);
  });
```

Comment: as on the example, the value 'app' needs to come from a.host.attributes.start.value and that, even using PLATFORM.moduleName will not work, like (using TS) a.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName(a.host.attributes.getNamedItem('start').value))